# Is there a charting library that supports multiple stacked column charts on the same 3D axes?

Tags: java, flash, charts

I have a very specific requirement that I can't find a charting library for. I need to show multiple stacked column or step-area charts on the same 3D axes to compare multiple periods of time to each other - for example, the y axis would show sales volume with regions stacked above each other, the x axis hours of the day and the z axis selected days to compare. In addition, I'd like the chart to be real 3D and draggable rather than a basic static isometric view.

There is an expensive Java library that [may be able to do an isometric version of the chart I need](http://www.objectplanet.com/easycharts/doc/overlay.html) called [EasyCharts](http://www.objectplanet.com/easycharts/); it's visual quality isn't as good as I'd like. None of the Flash libraries I found ([AnyChart](http://www.anychart.com/home/), [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), [XML/SWF Charts](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/)) can combine multiple stacked charts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d, which will really help you to do what you want. It's for Java.
Regards,
Martin